# Efficient javascript equivalent of Processing functions

Tags: javascript, processing

I tweaked a Processing sketch to produce a variant of a TV static effect I need for a web app. Now I want to convert this effect into JS/canvas. What are the pure javascript/canvas equivalents of `loadPixels()`, `copyArray()`, `updatedPixels()`, and `draw()` as given in the following Processing code, or how best to go about the conversion given that, probably, JS/canvas are not *as efficient* as Processing/Java?

```
int[] ppx;
Random generator = new Random();

void setup() {
  size(640,480);
  loadPixels();  
  ppx = new int[pixels.length];
  for (int y = 0; y < ppx.length;y++) {
      int spread = generator.nextInt(5);
      switch(spread) {
        case(1):
            if(y-480 > 0) {
                ppx[y] = ppx[y-480];
            }
            break;
        case(2):
            if(y-1 > 0) {
                ppx[y] = ppx[y-1];
            }
            break;
        case(3):
            ppx[y] = color(0,generator.nextInt(2)*255,0);
            if(y+480 < ppx.length) {
                ppx[y+480] = ppx[y];
            }
            break;
        case(4):
            ppx[y] = color(0,generator.nextInt(2)*255,0);
            if(y+1 < ppx.length) {
                ppx[y+1] = ppx[y];
            }
            break;
        case(0):
            break;
      };
  }
  frameRate(100000000000L);

}
void draw() {
  for (int y = 0; y < height;)
     arrayCopy(ppx, generator.nextInt(height/2), pixels, y++*width,width);
  updatePixels();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented these functions so far with s pointing to a HTMLCanvasElement. Jury is still out on whether [arrayCopy can be improved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15501573/907415) without [loop unrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448943/javascript-fastest-way-of-copying-an-array-portion-into-another):

```
    var x = s.getContext('2d');
    var pixels;
    function arrayCopy(src,sstart,dst,dstart,length) {
            length += sstart;
            dstart += length;
            while(--length > sstart) {
                    dst[--dstart] = src[length];    
            }       
    }
    function loadPixels() {
            pixels = x.getImageData(0,0,s.width,s.height);
    }
    function updatePixels() {
            x.putImageData(0,0,pixels);
    }
```

I'm still unsure about how to make the JS equivalent of a `draw()` function.

Comment: draw() is a loop, like while(true){do stuff}. It also try to keep frame rate stable. You may look into the source: https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java

Answer (score 1):

You can use John Resig's Processing.js for a one shot conversion:
http://processingjs.org/

Canvas and JS works is a bit more low level maybe start here : 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/canvas-from-scratch-pixel-manipulation/

Comment: Try looking through that net.tutsplus article I saw at least two of the functions in there that you were looking for.

Comment: maybe it fails cause of Random, wich is plain java. Processingjs can't translate pure java. Try with built in function random()
http://processing.org/reference/random_.html