# Is this as fast as JS array copy can get without loop unrolling?

Tags: javascript, optimization

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15501251/907415).

I have heard that the while pattern with a decrement and a greater than test is faster than any other loop pattern. Given that, is this the fastest possible array copy in js?

```
    function arrayCopy(src,sstart,dst,dstart,length) {
            length += sstart;
            dstart += length;
            while(--length >= sstart) {
                    dst[--dstart] = src[length];    
            }       
    }
```

Other test functions

```
       function slowCopy(src,sstart,dst,dstart,length) {
               for(var i = sstart; i < sstart+length;i+=1 ) {
                      dst[dstart++] = src[i];
               }
       }

       function aCopy(src,sstart,dst,dstart,length) {
              Array.prototype.splice.apply(dst,[dstart, length].concat(src.slice(sstart,sstart+length)));
       }
```

**Test Results** http://jsperf.com/fastest-js-arraycopy

arrayCopy -

```
2,899
±5.27%
fastest
```

slowCopy - **WINNER**

```
2,977
±4.86%
fastest
```

aCopy -

```
2,810
±4.61%
fastest
```

I want to add some more of the suggested functions below to the jsPerf tests but none of them incorporate source start offset, destination start offset or length of copy. Anyway, I was somewhat surprised by these results which appear to be the opposite of what I expect

Comment: You can do some tests: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: if you need a given `dstart`/`length`, your loop is fine. Deleting my answer as it'd be a little off-topic.

Comment: Though, I'm pretty sure that you can use `Array.splice` for that, though I'm not sure how your performance will work out.

Comment: How many items approx do you have in the `src` array/do you intend to copy with each iteration? I've made another approach but I'd like to test it on jsPerf before posting.

Comment: Okay, cool. I have about 640 per iteration. And about 480 iterations ;)

Comment: Oh your loop seems to be faster then. Tested from 500 to 2500 iterations, your loops runs faster on V8 http://jsperf.com/while-vs-splice-slice

Comment: As your code is fully functional, I believe you may get better answers on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow Copy is, surprisingly, the winner. By a narrow margin:

```
 function slowCopy(src,sstart,dst,dstart,length) {
           for(var i = sstart; i < sstart+length;i+=1 ) {
                  dst[dstart++] = src[i];
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Who says you need a loop?

```
var myArrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

This method makes a deep clone of the array. Here it is in a function:

```
function arrayCopy(src,sstart,dst,dstart,length) {
        dst = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(src));   
}
```

Keep in mind the other variables (besides `src` and `dst`) are there just to maintain your original code structure in case you have pre-existing calls to this function. They won't be used and can be removed.

Comment: Cool idea.  
Could you rewrite your code using src and dst to copy insert?

Comment: Thanks. sstart and dstart and length are relevant however.

Comment: Why didn't you mention that before?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the fastest way:

```
var original = [1, 2, 3];
var copy = original.slice(0);
```

Comment: Yes it is, but OP wants to insert elements from a start to length into a given offset of the other array, not create a new one.

Comment: Indeed. I read the post without really evaluating the example code.